# Rails: unable to set any attribute of child model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having a problem instantiating a `ListItem` object with specified attributes. For some reason all attributes are set to `nil` even if I specify values. However, if I specify attributes for a `List`, they retain their values.

Attributes for a `List` retain their values:

```
>> list = List.new(:id => 20, :name => "Test List")
=> #<List id: 20, name: "Test List">
```

Attributes for a `ListItem` **don't** retain their values:

```
>> list_item = ListItem.new(:id => 17, :list_id => 20, :name => "Test Item")
=> #<ListItem id: nil, list_id: nil, name: nil>
```

---

**UPDATE #1**:

I thought the `id` was the only attribute not retaining its value but realized that setting any attribute for a `ListItem` gets set to `nil`.

---

**UPDATE #2**:

I added `validates_associated :list_items` to the `List` class which alleviated an error regarding the `name` attribute being blank.

However, I still can't explicitly assign an `id` to a new `ListItem`.

---

**list.rb:**

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :list_items, :dependent => :destroy

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :list_items, 
                                  :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:name].blank? }, 
                                  :allow_destroy => true
end
```

**list_item.rb:**

```
class ListItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :list

    validates_presence_of :name  
end
```

**schema.rb**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20100506144717) do

  create_table "list_items", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "list_id"       
    t.string   "name"       
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "lists", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"        
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"        
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created your models and tables in my local setup. I didn't encounter any errors. There must be some class name conflict OR you have some before_save filters/observers resetting the values.

**Note**

I would change the model names to be bit more specific. It is very easy to run in to class name conflicts with names like `List` and `ListItem`

Answer (score 0):

Hmm,

I've encountered something similar when validations don't work properly. Try

```
ListItem.create!(:id => 17, :list_id => 20, :name => "Test Item")
```

This should give you more direct feedback if the model is invalid.

Comment: I get the following error message when I execute the above statement: "ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Name can't be blank"

I'm not sure why it's throwing this error when the name attribute is clearly not blank.

Comment: It could be that you're specifying `:id`. Try taking that out

Comment: I took `:id` out and I'm still getting: `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Name can't be blank`. I'm perplexed.

Comment: I added `validates_associated :list_items` to the `List` class which seemed to fix the `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Name can't be blank` error but I still can't create a `ListItem` with a specified `:id`.

Comment: True. I was trying to avoid that so I could figure out the underlying cause of the issue.